# Change CSS position of each element in a DIV using JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a Div with `position:relative` which contains "one or more" images inside it with `postion:absolute` with some top and left values. I need to toggle the position attribute of ALL THE IMAGES at a time between `Absolute` and `Auto/Relative` with a button using JS or JQuery.
Is there any way to work with all these child IMAGES at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/15x15/000/fff" class='absPosition'>
</div>
<input type="button" value="change position">
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
.absPosition {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    $("img").toggleClass("absPosition")
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRDdB/

Comment: exactly what I was thinking, but you were a tad faster. :D +1!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a jQuery selector which encompasses all of the images within your div. If, for example, your div had an id of "divId" then to set the position to relative of all the images within that div, you would use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#divId img").css("position", "relative")
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be best achieved using both CSS rules (as in CSS rules, not JS assigned inline styles) and jQuery's `.toggleClass()` method.

If you've got markup like the following:

```
<div id='foo'>
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
```

and CSS like the following:

```
div#foo { position:relative; }
div#foo img { position:relative; }
div#foo img.absolute { position:absolute; }
```

You can easily toggle that the `IMG`s' position rule using something like

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div#foo img').toggleClass('absolute');
});
```